# "Last 30 days + today" in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

When selecting date ranges in Google Analytics, one is always missing for me:

```
Last 30 days + today
```

Is there a way to define this custom date range, or should I always define it manually?

Comment: I got frustrated with Google Analytics defaults so now I access my reporting through here: http://ostermiller.org/calc/ga.html  I've built it in such a way that you can add your own report id and bookmark that to get all sorts of date links.  However, I didn't include the +today link you are looking for.  Seeing a partial day of data isn't very useful unless you are looking at the hourly reports as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Waw, cool! it would be nice to add a "include today" checkbox on that tool. Something else: once the URL is built with your tool, can I bookmark it, or does it included the dates *hardcoded* in the URL?

Comment: GA only allows hard coded dates in its URLs as far as I know.  :-(    I bookmark my tool with the report id.    Every time you visit, the JS in the page puts the new dates into the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Create a PHP file on your own server, like `example.com/myanalytics/index.php` (don't worry, it will just create an URL *shortcut* to anlaytics, so nobody will be able to see it even if they visit this page):

```
<?php
$myid = 'aXXXXXXXwXXXXXXXXXpXXXXXXXXX';
$end = date('Ymd');     // this is today :)
$start = date('Ymd', time()-31*24*3600);
header('Location: https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#report/visitors-overview/' . $myid . '/%3F_u.date00%3D' . $start . '%26_u.date01%3D' . $end . '%26overview-graphOptions.selected%3Danalytics.nthDay/');    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain you will have to use the custom date range functionality always for that date range. The only other tip I have is that you can select a whole month by clicking on it [image]

Comment: Yes but then we have to select the range manually (start date, end date), that's what I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your exact use case is, but I've run into this when I'm bookmarking GA views I use frequently (and want those views to incorporate the newest data).

If you replace the end date query string parameter with a date in the future, the view will incorporate data up through and including today.

_u.date00=20190829&_u.date01=**20501230**